# how to pass list from javascript to servlet through ajax?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I get list on my jsp using

```
 <%List selectedArray = (List) session.getAttribute("clist");%>
```

is [4,5].And I am sending this list to javascript using hidden variable in jsp

```
 <input type='hidden' id="agencycontactid" name="agencycontactid" value="<%=selectedArray%>" />
```

and i am taking this in javascript `var abc=$('#agencycontactid').val();` .
I want to send this abc to servlet using ajax call that is through data.And i want this list in simple array format in servlet.
Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna pass an actual array (ie. an indexed array) then you can do:

```
 $.post('/url', {'someKeyName': ['value','value']});
```

You can also build a param string by looping other the data (in my case a multi-select)

```
$(".choosenItems option").each(function() {
        chosenStr = chosenStr + "&chItems=" + $(this).val();
});
```

so if you create a queryString of

```
   ...?name=Fred&name=Joe&name=Sally
```

then in your servlet you can do

```
String names[] = request.getParameterValues ("name");
```

Comment: so in that case the second option is suitable.

Comment: i didn't get ur answer.

Comment: Does this answer you question?

Comment: That would make no functional difference.  If this question helped you please consider accepting this answer and/or upvoting it.